# Conversion of single string to list of strings when new strings are added

Tags: python, string

I can't find an answer.
I read a dictionary from file, it has a string value for a key.
Then I check if a new value is already in the dictionary, if it isn't then I want
to append it to the previous string and to get a list of values for a given key.

For example if I have a dictionary

```
dict = {"vehicles": "car", "animals": "cat"}
```

and the following condition is true

```
if "dog" not in dict["animals"]:
```

I'd like to get the output

```
dict = {"vehicles": "car", "animals": ["cat", "dog"] }
```

Comment: Heres a few tips to know. Dicts are unordered, meaning they don't store the positions of the keys. Also, using `dict` as a var name is a bad idea, since `dict` is the dict class.

Comment: @Qwerty, Is it true for json type in python?

Comment: If you want order, I believe you are looking for an ordered dict, which I believe is in the collections library.

Comment: It is valuable remark, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to try append the element to the list and if it fails make the dictionary value a list:

```
dic = {"vehicles": "car", "animals": "cat"}
if "dog" not in dic["animals"]:
    try:
        dic["animals"].append("dog")
    except:
        dic["animals"] = [dic["animals"], "dog"]
```

Gives output:

```
{'vehicles': 'car', 'animals': ['cat', 'dog']}
```

In this way if you have a single element the `except` part will be executed, making the value a list of string. If you then try to add another element it will be appended to the list.

Comment: Thanks, but for me It gives {'vehicles': 'car', 'animals': [['cat'], 'dog']}

Comment: Yeah it works, what is the difference from Jonathan R answer? Is it  due to exception? Why does append() work with string here?

Comment: Jonathan answer will produce nested lists in case you append more than one item. Here it will not. `append` will not work on strings, it will give you an exception, hence the `try/except`

Answer (score 4):

start with a dictionary with values as `set` of strings

```
d = {"vehicles": {"car"}, "animals": {"cat"}}
```

Then adding twice a new value only adds it once (and lookup is fast since it uses hashes):

```
d["animals"].add('dog')
d["animals"].add('dog')

>>> d
{'animals': {'dog', 'cat'}, 'vehicles': {'car'}}
```

If you have the dictionary as input like in your question, you can transform it easily with values as set with dictionary comprehension like this:

```
loaded_d = {"vehicles": "car", "animals": "cat"}  # dict just loaded from file
d = {key:{value} for key,value in loaded_d.items()}
```

Comment: Ok, should I convert values to sets when I read a dictionary from a file?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `update` animals *list* by using `append` method.

```
dict = {"vehicles": "car", "animals": "cat"}

def appendItem(item):
  if item not in dict["animals"]:
      if not isinstance(dict["animals"], list):
          dict["animals"] = [dict["animals"]]
      dict["animals"].append(item)

appendItem("dog")
appendItem("dog")
appendItem("rabbit")
appendItem("cat")
```

Output

```
=> {'vehicles': 'car', 'animals': ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> if "dog" not in dict["animals"]:
...     dict["animals"] = [dict["animals"], "dog"]
```

Comment: try to add a third animal that will nest your list once more.

Comment: that's not in the problem statement

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it would be good to append more strings and get just a list of strings as @ Jean-François Fabre noticed

Answer (score 1):

Should be the easies way I think

```
dict = {"vehicles": {"car"}, "animals": {"cat"}}
if "dog" not in dict["animals"]:
    dict["animals"].add("dog")
```